# Protecting the on-board flash memory content on Raspberry Pi 3 SOM

Tags: software-development, security, compute-module-3

I'm using the Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3 (CM3) in my latest hardware product for networking and user interface function, as it has small form factor and solid availability (until 2023 according to the datasheet).

[image]

I would like to bundle my software into the on-board-flash in a way that it would be difficult to get it off from there and modify. I understand that if someone really wants to get my software then they can just unsolder the flash from my CM3 and read it on some other system, but is there a way to protect the content (like micro-controllers have the fuse bits to make the flash content non-readable over the debug/programming line). My Linux image is read-only. All the data generated by the device is saved on external SD card and configurations are held in external FRAM.

Comment: So you're selling a device using a GPL OS, but not including source to your own software? I'm pretty sure that goes against the GPL license...

Comment: I can provide the OS source, but I don't have to provide my application source (that is just running on that OS). I don't want to protect the OS part, just my application specific binary.

Comment: Technically speaking. I'm selling hardware and application specific binary, not the OS. OS is something that I give away for free (with the source) :)

Comment: Just be careful what you're linking with: not all libraries are LGPL, and some (for instance [GNU Readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline#Choice_of_the_GPL_as_GNU_Readline.27s_license "GNU Readline")) can only be used in software released under a licence compatible with the GPL.